# How to perform the click event of a RichTextBox by clicking on ANOTHER RichTextBox

Tags: richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox.Click event and another RichTextBox I am using as a label to the first RichTextBox.
I want to activate the event handler of the first RichTextBox.Click event when the second RichTextBox (the label) is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will you

Window form have 2 RichTextBox and 2 label ,when you click on RichTextBox2 at the time also fired  RichTextBox1_Click with help of below code

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Click
    lblforRichTextBox1.Text = "Fired RichTextBox1 " & System.DateTime.Now()
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.Click
    lblForRichTextBox2.Text = "Fired RichTextBox2 " & System.DateTime.Now()
    RichTextBox1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```